# Find the object in the image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I need to find only the tiger object in this picture by applying segmentation operations and other operations, but I don't know much about it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzgfH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any research before asking? Stack Overflow is not meant to solve your project for you. Also, in my experience openCV has a pretty steep learning curve. By someone giving you some code that does what you want you'll learn nothing. You'll learn most by trying for yourself. A lot.

With that being said, below is some code that removes background. It is very basic and specific to your image. In general it is **not** very good, as you can see in the result. But since your new to opencv maybe it is not too complex for you to understand.

I would encourage you to research the operations that are done in the code until you understand them. (read [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html), [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) and [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html)) Look at the images before and after the operations to see what it does. Then, when you're up for it, you can create a better backgroundsubtractor yourself by following [this tutorial](http://www.codepasta.com/site/vision/segmentation/) or by using [grabcut](https://pythonprogramming.net/grabcut-foreground-extraction-python-opencv-tutorial/)

Result:

[image]

```
# load image
img = cv2.imread("animal.jpg")
# detect edges
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,100)
# merge edges to big blob
kernel =  np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)
edges = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
# detect contour of blob
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# draw filled contour on edges-img
for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(edges, [cnt], 0, (255,255,255), -1)
# uses edges-img as mask to remove background
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=edges)
cv2.imshow("img", res) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```